# ngnix location breaking node (sails) routes

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js, nginx-location

I have been looking for the `correct nginx configuration to achieve a server location (different from /) and get node routes working`.

### Context

- Node application running on http://localhost:1337
- Nginx server with proxy_pass pointing to node application
- Server **location** property **/app**
- http requests redirected to https

### Nginx config file

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    domain.com;
  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  #listen 80 default_server;
  #listen [::]:80 default_server;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain.com;
  # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location /app {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
  }
}
```

### Problem

When navigating to **www.domain.com/app** I get the correct node home page.

Then, when requesting **www.domain.com/app/test**, I would expect it to bring me http://localhost:1337/test. That is not happening, I get a 404 not found instead. So, for some reason, `the location isn't recognizing node routing`.

The curious thing is that **if location is / instead of /app, everything is working as expected**. Therefore, the problem might be related to the location.

### Possible fixes

I've already tried to add a rewrite under location with no luck:

```
location /app {
  rewrite ^/app(.*) /$1 break;
  ...
}
```

---

Do you have an idea of why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to map the front-end URI `/app/test` to the upstream URI `/test` then you are missing a trailing `/` on your `location` directive. Try:

```
location /app/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/;
    ...
}
```

Notice that both `location` and `proxy_path` have a trailing `/`.

Of course, it means that the URI `/app` will not work anymore, but you can fix that easily with:

```
location = /app { rewrite ^ /app/ last; }
```

or:

```
location = /app { return 301 /app/; }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.